Win11 two taskbar icons for two different Terminal applications?
In Win10, I pinned two different command-line applications to the Taskbar as my first and second applications. That let me launch them and switch to them with Win+1 and Win+2. Great!
In Win11, these shortcuts act only as launchers to open Terminal as a separate application. When I use Win+1, it launches another instance of the application instead of switching to the existing one. When I launch the application, it doesn't show the active dot below the icon -- instead it's added a Terminal icon to the taskbar.
Note that this problem isn't because the Terminal windows are being combined, so changing the Taskbar behaviors setting doesn't help. I want to pin two different scripts that run as console applications instead of two scripts that run in Terminal.

While the Win11 Terminal supports tabs, my applications aren't opening as different tabs int the same window, so it's not that either.
How can I setup two shortcuts that launch as their own application? (In this case, my two applications are an Ubuntu WSL window and a script that launches the game I'm developing.)

Specifics:
My shortcut in %AppData%\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch\User Pinned\TaskBar looks like this:

Target: C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k C:\bin\run_forever.py C:/bin/run_game.bat
Start in: C:\bin\

The second one was created by launching Ubuntu from start and pinning it, but now launching it like that also opens Terminal.

With wsltty, you can get a WSL terminal for linux and multiple batch programs. wsltty comes with mintty which is an alternative to the built-in Windows Terminal.
These steps worked for me:

Create a shortcut that runs wsltty with a batch file and pin to taskbar:

Example Target: %USERPROFILE%\scoop\apps\wsltty\current\bin\mintty.exe --exec C:\bin\run_program_here.bat
This will pin as the shortcut you setup. You can repeat this to pin multiple different shortcuts.


Create a shortcut that runs cmd.exe and pin to taskbar:

Example Target: C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k C:\bin\run_another_program.bat
This will pin as a generic Terminal app. All other uses of Terminal will be folded into this taskbar icon.


Hit Win and type "WSL Terminal", launch that, and pin it to taskbar.

For me, running this started Ubuntu.



I created all of these shortcuts on my desktop. You can drag and drop that mintty.exe to your desktop and select "Create shortcuts here". Then view properties and modify the Target and Start directory.
If you use scoop and have extras setup, install with: scoop install wsltty
